# Kafka transactions how to emulate an error to rollback transaction

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-transactions, kafka-transactions-api

I want to test Kafka transactional behavior in depth. I need to test what happens in the transaction boundary if this is a possibility.

For example, I want the commit of the transaction to fail so that I can test what happens during a transaction rollback.

Is this possible?

For example, when talking about database transactions, one easy way to test a failed transaction is to try to persist a record with an field with length greater than the maximum.

But in Kafka I don't know how to emulate something similar to trigger the kafka transaction rollback.